# conditional highlight one column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a basic pandas dataframe.

I am trying to conditional highlight **just one column**.

I have tried to follow the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html

I have got to this point for the dataframe `df`:

```py
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: blue" if x>0 else "background-color: green")
```

I am able to generate a rule for the **whole table** like this:

[image]

But how can i apply the rule to **just one column** for example the `wav` column ?

Answer (score 0):

With the `subset` arguement I have now managed to do this:

```py
def format_df(x):
    if x>0:
        return "background-color: blue"
    else:
        return "background-color: green"
    

diffs.style.applymap(lambda x: format_df(x), subset=['wav'])
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Is there a way to calibrate such that there is a heatmap ?